# Alert doesn't execute after anchor click in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, anchor

I have the next code:

```
 $('.ver').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next().val();
    $.post('cotizar_detalles.php', {'id': id})
            .done(function(response) {
                $('#detalles').dialog('open').dialog('option', 'title', 'Detalles')
                        .html(response, function() {
                            $('.corregir').click(function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                alert('aqui toy');
                            });
                        });
            });
});
```

Where ".ver" and ".corregir" are both class inside an anchor tag.
'.corregir' exists on the html after the ajax.response.
The problem is the last alert, inside the '.corregir' click event doesn't execute, and I need it to execute another action.
What's the problem?
And thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.click() is a direct binding in jQuery which only works on elements in the DOM on page load.  Try using a delegated binding instead, such as $.on():

```
$(body).on('click', '.corregir', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('aqui toy');
});
```

Check out the [.on() jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: "...which only works on elements in the DOM on page load..." 
Thank u so much! That's explain a lot of problems that I had. 
I know about the 'on' event, but I don't know about the second.
Now to work!

Comment: You're welcome!  .on() is the preferred selector for most events in jQuery these days as it works on ALL elements, included those generated by AJAX.  It can also be used for many different kinds of events, including click, change, mouseover, etc.